# Set HTML signature with base64 image in Outlook Web app by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I have tried to set HTML signature for users of Outlook Web. 
The htm file (`E:\mysignature.htm`) is openned fine in the browser displaying the image. 
The image is encoded in base64, therefore in HTML file, 
  the tag is `img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K....'`

I then save the file and run the following PowerShell commands:

```
$SignatureHtml = Get-Content "E:\mysignature.htm" | Out-String 

Set-MailboxMessageConfiguration -Identity $userName -AutoAddSignature $true -SignatureHtml $SignatureHtml
```

The script ran without error, but the html signature shows the tag `<img src="" >`
All text inside src quotes were stripped.

Any idea would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding base64 image in this way worked for me.

```
<img src="" style=""><span id="dataURI" style="display:none">data:image/png;base64,IMAGE_DATA_HERE</span>
```

I got this from https://katystech.blog/2018/06/office-365-automated-signature-generator/

> The above code probably won’t work if you try it out in a web browser
> as it’s completely non-standard

Comment: Keep in mind that inline images like that won't work in older versions of desktop Outlook

Answer (score -1):

Part of the problem might be that `Get-Content` splits files into lines by default.  Try using the `-Raw` parameter on `Get-Content`. This will read and return the file as a single piece of text.

```
$SignatureHtml = Get-Content "E:\mysignature.htm" -Raw
```

Also: piping through `Out-String` as in the original example is unnecessary, the data is already a string.